# Is it possible to save a new Grails domain instance without fetching referenced domains?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a user_id (for User domain) and want to save a new instance of another domain referencing that User without fetching the User instance. Is this possible? I tried:

```
User user = User.load(user_id)
new Action(user: user, foo: "bar").save()
```

This fetches the user. I also tried:

```
User user = new User(id: user_id)
new Action(user: user, foo: "bar").save()
```

This also fetches the user.

I need this to work for performance reasons and don't want to have to insert the rows using JDBC if I can avoid that. I am using Grails 3.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried to `discard` the domain class?

Comment: Unfortunately discard does't work. The user is fetched as soon as discard is called.

Answer (score 2):

This is dark side of ORM and you won't be able to do it without bypassing GORM. ORM only knows about Objects and Classes. Tables, columns and other database stuffs are not in ORM's dictionary. The other option is to create a service for this and in this service use POGO (groovy version of POJO) to interact with databases.

Comment: I have used another ORM that didn't have any trouble with this use-case. So I am hoping there is a way with GORM or perhaps Hibernate directly.

Comment: JDO Genie, a Java Data Objects implementation, from many years ago.